# How to connect a Twitter Account while using Next Auth Credentials Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, twitter, next-auth

in my app users can register and login into their accounts - this is already handled by NextAuth. But I want to implement this feature where users can connect their Social Media Accounts like Twitter can post tweets. Can I use the Next Auth Twitter Provider for that or will the session / cookies get overridden?

What's the best option to add a "connect twitter account" (to the account they have in my app) feature?

Comment: What have you tried? NextAuth have integration for twitter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I just want to know how the users can be signed in using 2 providers. The first one is the credentials provider and the second one is the twitter provider because I have a feature in my Web App that requires Twitter Authentication. However I dont want the cookies etc to change to twitter login because the user should still be logged in with his credentials. Do you know what I mean?